# How to specify dyad and subject ID random factors in an MCMC model in R?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, glmm, dyadic-data

I am working on a model to analyze a categorical outcome variable (7 categories) for a design with two fixed factors (Condition and Group) as well as the random factors of Subject ID nested in Dyad ID. I know how to do this type of nesting in lmer, but I am unsure in MCMCglmm.

I am using the MCMCglmm package and I have put my current code below, where I have left Condition out for now (as it has not been previously significant in earlier models, which is confirmed visually; this also simplifies the model), and I currently only have DyadID included as a random factor.

In addition, following previous tutorials and advice, the trait variable included.

**My question:** How do I include Subject ID and nest it appropriately in this model? Also, if I do so, how does trait relate to this and what is the effect on the prior?

````
prior5 <- list(R = list(fix = 1, V = 0.5 * ((diag(6)) + (matrix(rep(1, (6)^2), c(6, 6)))), n = 6),
               G = list(G1 = list(V = diag(6), n = 6, nu = 6, alpha.mu = rep(0,6), alpha.V = diag(6)*a),
                        G2 = list(V = diag(2), n = 2, nu = 2, alpha.mu = rep(0,2), alpha.V = diag(2)*a)))


m3 <- MCMCglmm(QT2 ~ -1 + trait + Group,
                          random = ~ us(trait):DyadID + us(Group):DyadID,
                          rcov = ~ us(trait):units,
                          prior = prior5,
                          burnin = 5000,
                          nitt = 18000,
                          family = "categorical",
                          data = mcmc.Q2)
```
````